# AngularJS - custom filter errors due to undefined arrays and still filters properly?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of objects getting assigned to `$scope` within a controller, and is being filtered in a series of divs within a partial template:

```
  <div class="entity-list">
    <!-- Folders -->
    <div class="entity-listing folder" ng-repeat="child in folders | filterName:nameFilter | entityType:filterType | orderBy:orderProp:orderAscDesc">
      <!-- Some HTML -->
    </div>
    <!-- Files -->
    <div class="entity-listing document" ng-repeat="child in documents | filterName:nameFilter | entityType:filterType | orderBy:orderProp:orderAscDesc">
      <!-- Some HTML -->
    </div>
  </div>
```

The filters are displayed in a separate `fieldset` element:

```
  <fieldset id="filters">
    <legend>Filters</legend>
    <label for="filter-name">Name Contains:</label>
    <input id="filter-name" ng-model="nameFilter">
    <label for="filter-type">Show:</label>
    <select id="filter-type" ng-model="filterType">
      <!-- some options -->
    </select>
    <label for="sort-field">Sort By:</label>
    <select id="sort-field" ng-model="orderProp">
      <!-- some options -->
    </select>
    <select ng-model="orderAscDesc">
      <!-- some options -->
    </select>
  </fieldset>
```

I have a module set up with two filters, and pass that module on to my app:

```
angular.module('widget', ['filters']).
  config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/homefolder', {templateUrl: 'widget/partial/entity-list.html', controller: HomeFolderCtrl}).
      when('/folder/:uuid', {templateUrl: 'widget/partial/entity-list.html', controller: FolderCtrl}).
      otherwise({redirectTo: '/homefolder'});
  }]);
angular.module('filters', []).
  filter('entityType', function() {
    return function(items, type) {
      var returnArray = [];
      for (var i=0,ii=items.length;i<ii;i++) {
        if (type == "both") {
          returnArray.push(items[i]);
        } else if (items[i].type == type) {
          returnArray.push(items[i]);
        }
      }
      return returnArray;
    }
  }).
  filter('filterName', function() {
    return function(items, str) {
      var returnArray = [];
      if (str != '') {
        for (var i=0,ii=items.length;i<ii;i++) {
          if (items[i].name.indexOf(str) !== -1) {
            returnArray.push(items[i]);
          }
        }
      } else {
        returnArray = items;
      }
      return returnArray;
    }
  });
```

I'm concerned that this code works, yet when looking at the error console, I get a bunch of errors saying `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` regarding the `filterName` and `entityType` filters' for loops.  If I wrap those filter in an if statement to check if `items` is defined (take for example `filterName`):

```
  filter('filterName', function() {
    return function(items, str) {
      var returnArray = [];
      if (items) {
        if (str != '') {
          for (var i=0,ii=items.length;i<ii;i++) {
            if (items[i].name.indexOf(str) !== -1) {
              returnArray.push(items[i]);
            }
          }
        } else {
          returnArray = items;
        }
      }
      return returnArray;
    }
  });
```

It gets rid of the error and works as well.  Why would AngularJS pass in undefined `item`s to the filters?  Where else could these filters be getting called if they are only explicitly getting called in my two `ng-repeat`s?

Comment: because you may want to deal with undefined or null in your filters, it is a sensible design choice IMO (you can write a default filter that check null or undefined and replace with a provided value for exemple: `yourArrayPromise | default: []`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Is it safe to assume that the data going through your filters is retrieved from the server asynchronously? When the page first renders, and angular goes through everything, there is no data yet, so it is undefined. Once the data returns, it goes through the digest cycle again, and then there is data this time, so it all works. For this reason, it's a good idea to have the defined check at the beginning of the filter function.

Comment: Yes, the `folders` and `documents` scope arrays are retrieved asynchronously.  I would have assumed that the `ng-repeat` (and subsequent filters there-in) would only execute if the arrays existed... I guess not?

Comment: Maybe you want your filter to do something with the value if it's `undefined`? This kind of thing irked me when I was getting started, but I've come to accept it as necessary. One thing you can do is initialize the variable to an empty array when the controller starts or in an `ng-init` directive, e.g. `<div class="entity-list" ng-init="folders = []">`

Comment: Excellent, initializing the values in the controller makes more sense then checking with if statements in the filters.  Thanks!

Comment: Thought i had lost my mind.. lol thanks! in the filter i put `if ( angular.isUndefined(data) return data )`

Answer (score 0):

When the page renders, Angular examines everything. if in initial stage data is coming empty , then you should put check for undefined.

```
      app.filter('greaterThenHundred', function () {
    return function (items) {

        if (items == undefined)
            items = [];
        var filtered = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            var item = items[i];
            if (item.Salary > 100) {
                filtered.push(item);
            }
        }
        return filtered;
    };
});
```